# Non-interactive login to Azure AD using ADAL4J java

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, adal4j

I have a web application for which users are being managed in the Azure AD. Every time a user logs in the app, the app should be able to authenticate the user against Azure AD in a non-interactive way. I am able to get the access token to my app registered in AD using the admin account. Now using this token I want to be able to authenticate a user in the AD. How is this possible using the ADAL4J api?

Comment: Did you want to authenticate a user within username & password? If so, please refer to the sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-native-headless. If not, I think you want to use the access token of getting via admin authenication to authenicate other users using graph api, then you need to refer to the sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks @PeterPan-MSFT I was able to authenticate users using username and password as explained in github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-native-headle‌​ss. Although initially I was getting an error saying "The user or administrator has not consented to use the application ". Once I provided the consent using the global administrator the authentication started working.